# Find smallest value of Vector3D list

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

my Vector3D is just basic X Y Z struct. I want to find the smallest Y value from Vector3D list. Actually I'm doing it in foreach but it's slow. Also I don't know why my foreach not always returns smallest Y.

```
float rAngle = 3000.0f;
foreach (Vector3D target in targets)
{
     if (target.Y - PlayerAngles.Y < rAngle && target.Y - PlayerAngles.Y > -rAngle)
     {
          rAngle = target.Y - PlayerAngles.Y;
          finalAngle = target;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)'s `Min()` function for looping through the whole list in a single line. See below code for example. You can customise the lambda expression `x => x.Y` to your specific needs.

```
static void testVec() 
{
   List<Vector3D> vec = new List<Vector3D>();

   vec.Add(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0));
   vec.Add(new Vector3D(0, -1, 0));
   vec.Add(new Vector3D(0, 2, 0));

   double min_y = vec.Min(x => x.Y);
}
```